# Do you get an extra turn at the end of the age?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

If you build a wonder that gives you another turn **as the last turn in an age**, and there are no cards left, do you forfeit the extra turn?

Answer (score 8):

In the rulebook in small italicized text on page ten above the header `1. Construct a Building`

it states:

> If a player has a replay effect that would allow them to take another turn at the end of an Age (when the structure is empty), the effect is lost.

Comment: See also https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1473041/another-turn-end-age

Comment: Had a friend try to argue that they should go first next round because they had an extra turn.

Comment: @Styxsksu - I could actually see that as a reasonable house rule if the conflict pawn is in the center of the board, rather than the last active player.